# How to get one paramater value from url in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the URL parameter and split it using jQuery. When the URL parameter value and the current page URL value are not equal it should be redirected.

**Code Sample**

```
$(".heading a").attr("href", "http://pacificwebtechnology.com/Facebook?val="+ variable + "#form-fill");

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("hai");
    function getUrlParameter(sParam) 
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('?');
        return sURLVariables;
    }​

    $var=getUrlParameter(val);

});
```

Comment: Where does `sParam` parameter in the function `getUrlParameter` gets used?

Comment: @José Tomás Tocino i'm asking for single variable ji.Need to split ? alone.